# How to prevent a class template and its specializations in a header from being hijacked?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

The detailed request is to MAKE such a header file that contains such a class template and a bunch of its specializations(partial or fully), maybe several member functions of them have also been included. Then, as long as the developer didn't modify the header file itself then she/he wouldn't have a chance to make her/his own specialization of the class template in the header file.

Here is a sample:
content in Header File 'MyIncl.h':

```
namespace n1
{
  template < typename _Ty >
  class MyTmplCls
  {
    typedef MyType1 OutputType;
  };

  template <>
  class MyTmplCls< MyType4Spec >
  {
    typedef MyType2 OutputType;
  };
}
```

Then someone can do this in his own source:

```
...
namespace n1
{
  template <>
  class MyTmplCls< YourType >
  {
    typedef YourSelfDefType1 OutputType;
  };
}
...
```

which is what i suppose to prevent.

Note that the question is how to make SUCH CLASS TEMPLATE(and the header file holding it, of course) rather than either 'How to prevent a header file from being modified' or 'How to prevent a class template from being specialized by its user without modifying the header file itself'. Simply words the key is the header file not 'without being modifed' but 'being modifed by who', and the answer of the later is 'Header's maker' ONLY.

These are what i have tried so far:
content in Header File 'MyIncl.h':

```
struct n1
{
  template < typename _Ty, DummyType >
  class MyTmplCls
  {
    typedef MyType1 OutputType;
  };

  template < DummyType _dt >
  class MyTmplCls< MyType4Spec, _dt >
  {
    typedef MyType2 OutputType;
  };
};
```

I thought a structure can't be redefined as long as your project has included the MyIncl.h.
But someone can still do this in his source:

```
...
template < DummyType _dt >
class n1::MyTmplCls< YourType, _dt >
{
  typedef YourSelfDefType1 OutputType;
};
...
```

I've found another way:

```
template < DummyType >
struct n1
{
  template < typename _Ty, DummyType >
  class MyTmplCls
  {
    typedef MyType1 OutputType;
  };

  template < DummyType _dt >
  class MyTmplCls< MyType4Spec, _dt >
  {
    typedef MyType2 OutputType;
  };
};
```

It's more restrict than the previous way although someone still can do something like this:

```
...
template <>
template < DummyType _dt >
class n1<0>::MyTmplCls< YourType, _dt >
{
  typedef YourSelfDefType1 OutputType;
};
...
```

The upper code sections just attempt to tell what i plan to do. They are not surely to be the right way.
　Okay... Now i need the real right way. Any useful tip will be appreciated.

** If you want to test by yourself, here is symbols that the upper code needed *******

```
typedef int MyType4Spec;
typedef long MyType1;
typedef short MyType2;
typedef int DummyType;
```

belongs to the header file, and

```
typedef void YourType;
typedef void YourSelfDefType1;
```

belongs to 'Your' source.

Comment: "Defend against Murphy, not against Machiavelli"

Comment: @MSalters Which is just what I am attempting to do.

Answer (score 2):

Why that paranoia - anything can be broken if a programmer is willing to !?

Hence, the answer is: There is no way.

Comment: What i supposed to make is a mechanism which can lead users of that header file using and applying the function of that template in right way as long as they have no attend to break in with the help of evil codes. shortly words i making this is for preventing any misuse rather than stop one to crush the code of header. If someone found that he can do something only when he was with the help of the evil way then he will give that way up as long as he dislike to ruin the code part of himself. 'anything can be broken' is not a good answer but just an excuse to be wrong.

Comment: @unituniverse - write good documentation. It's not your job to protect other programmers who don't read documentation.

Comment: It's obviouse if someone plans to crush it all he needs is to modify that header file directly and save to disk. It won't be bother to do something more complicat to make it happen.

Comment: @Pete Becker  The truth is: many guys use things made by others just depending on their feelings rather than reading provided documents carefully. When something wrong they did caused the bad result they prefer to complain about anything except the case of themselves. So the verification is still needed... more or less...

Comment: @unituniverse - it's true that some programmers don't bother to understand the code that they're using. People who do that deserve whatever happens to them.